# Normalizing constant and Marginal Probability

Tags: probability-theory

If I have a joint probability distribution,

$
\begin{array}{cc}
      \ f(x,y)=cxy & 0 < y < 2x < 2\\
\end{array}
$

and I wanted to find the normalizing constant $c$, and the marginal pdf of X, am I on the right track?

For the normalizing constant I tried

$c = \int_{0}^{2} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1}xy \,dx \ dy = 1$, and solving this I came up with a solution of $c=2$.

For the marginal pdf of X,

I have $f_{x}(x,y) = \int_{0}^{2x} 2xy \ dy$.

Do these integrals look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. (assuming your $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is cxy)

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you.